# File uploader with progress bar?

Tags: php, ajax, file, progress, uploader

How would I go about creating an HTML/PHP/AJAX file uploader with a progress bar? I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dojo [HTML5 Multi-File Uploader](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/uploader/) does all that and more. Highly recommended ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). Easy to integrate, lightweight and is a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.johnboy.com/php-upload-progress-bar/

this is the best i thing. no flash. only css jquery php

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this -> [Lpology | Simple Ajax Uploader](https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader)

its drop-dead-simple (my saying, whoops) and its sleeks interface, check it out!

Answer (score 0):

here is another option, this one lets you upload multiple files, but requires flash as well
http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.. [jqUploader](http://pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/test.php)

This is probably what you looking for.